# Django / Celery / Kombu worker error: Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?

Tags: django, message-queue, celery, worker, kombu

It seems as though messages are not getting put onto the queue properly.

I'm using Django with Celery and Kombu to make use of Django's own database as a Broker Backend. All I need is a very simple Pub/Sub setup. It will eventually deploy to Heroku, so I'm using foreman to run locally. Here is the relevant code and info:

**pip freeze**

```
Django==1.4.2
celery==3.0.15
django-celery==3.0.11
kombu==2.5.6
```

**Procfile**

```
web: source bin/activate; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 4; python manage.py syncdb
celeryd: python manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=INFO
```

**settings.py**

```
# Celery configuration
import djcelery
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("api.tasks",)
BROKER_URL = "django://localhost//"
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

**put_message**

```
with Connection(settings.BROKER_URL) as conn:
  queue = conn.SimpleQueue('celery')
  queue.put(id)
  queue.close()
```

**api/tasks.py**

```
@task()
def process_next_task():
  with Connection(settings.BROKER_URL) as conn:
    queue = conn.SimpleQueue('celery')
    message = queue.get(block=True, timeout=1)
    id = int(message.payload)
    try:
      Model.objects.get(id=id)
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
      message.reject()
    else:
      # Do stuff here
      message.ack()
    queue.close()
```

In the terminal, `foreman start` works just fine and shows this:

```
started with pid 31835
17:08:22 celeryd.1 | started with pid 31836
17:08:22 web.1     | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: source: not found
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31838] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.16.1
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31838] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (31838)
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31838] [INFO] Using worker: sync
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31843] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31843
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31844] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31844
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31845] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31845
17:08:22 web.1     | 2013-02-14 17:08:22 [31846] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31846
17:08:22 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-14 17:08:22,858: INFO/Beat] Celerybeat: Starting...
17:08:22 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-14 17:08:22,870: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@myhost.local ready.
17:08:22 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-14 17:08:22,873: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to django://localhost//.
17:08:42 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-14 17:08:42,926: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?
17:08:42 celeryd.1 | The full contents of the message body was: body: 25 (2b) {content_type:u'application/json' content_encoding:u'utf-8' delivery_info:{u'priority': 0, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}}
```

Those last two lines are not shown immediately, but get displayed when my API receives a POST request that runs the code in the **put_message** section above. I've experimented with using Kombu's fully blown-out Producer and Consumer classes with the same result.

Kombu's SimpleQueue example: http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/examples.html#hello-world-example
Celery Docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html

Any ideas?

**EDITED**

Changing to `--loglevel=DEBUG` within the procfile changes the terminal output to the following:

```
08:54:33 celeryd.1 | started with pid 555
08:54:33 web.1     | started with pid 554
08:54:33 web.1     | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: source: not found
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [557] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.16.1
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [557] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (557)
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [557] [INFO] Using worker: sync
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [564] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 564
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [565] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 565
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [566] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 566
08:54:36 web.1     | 2013-02-15 08:54:36 [567] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 567
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,480: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Loading modules.
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,484: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Claiming components.
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,484: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Building boot step graph.
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,484: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] New boot order: {ev, queues, beat, pool, mediator, autoreloader, timers, state-db, autoscaler, consumer}
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,489: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.beat._Process...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,490: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.beat._Process OK!
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,491: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,491: INFO/Beat] Celerybeat: Starting...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,506: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool OK!
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,507: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.mediator.Mediator...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,507: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.worker.mediator.Mediator OK!
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,507: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.consumer.BlockingConsumer...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,508: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@myhost.local ready.
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,508: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Re-establishing connection to the broker...
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,510: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to django://localhost//.
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,628: DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | <Entry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup() {<crontab: * 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>}
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,629: DEBUG/Beat] Celerybeat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
08:54:37 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:37,658: DEBUG/Beat] Celerybeat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
08:54:38 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:38,110: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
08:54:38 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:54:38,126: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Ready to accept tasks!
08:55:08 celeryd.1 | [2013-02-15 08:55:08,184: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?
08:55:08 celeryd.1 | The full contents of the message body was: body: 26 (2b) {content_type:u'application/json' content_encoding:u'utf-8' delivery_info:{u'priority': 0, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}}
```

Comment: Try changing --loglevel=INFO when running celery to --loglevel=DEBUG and see if it gives a more useful message.

Comment: When it says `The full contents of the message body was: body: 25 (2b)`, it means that the body was 2 bytes in size and consisted of the characters "2" and "5", which certainly does not look like a valid task message!

Comment: @njbooher I just added the DEBUG info, but it doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @asksol I agree that 2 bytes may not be enough for a task message, but this is exactly how Kombu documents its Hello World example in the link I provided, which is one of my main points of confusion. I'm looking for an example of how to get this to work or how to do it a different way that would work.

Comment: The celery task message format is documented here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html

Comment: The hello world example in the Python documentation uses a string payload, Celery doesn't use a string payload.  Every application can use multiple different message formats.

Comment: @asksol Thanks! Somehow I didn't come across the message format docs, but that helped a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was twofold:

The message format was wrong. It needs to be a dictionary according to the documentation at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html which @asksol provided, and following the example at the bottom of that page.

*Example Message*

```
{"id": "4cc7438e-afd4-4f8f-a2f3-f46567e7ca77",
 "task": "celery.task.PingTask",
 "args": [],
 "kwargs": {},
 "retries": 0,
 "eta": "2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191"}
```

**put_message**

```
with Connection(settings.BROKER_URL) as conn:
  queue = conn.SimpleQueue('celery')
  message = {
    'task': 'process-next-task',
    'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
    'args': [id],
    "kwargs": {},
    "retries": 0,
    "eta": str(datetime.datetime.now())
  }
  queue.put(message)
  queue.close()
```

The Procfile process is a consumer that runs the task, so there's no need to set up a consumer within the task. I just needed to use a parameters that I sent in when I published the message.

**api/tasks.py**

```
@task(serializer='json', name='process-next-task')
def process_next_task(id):
  try:
    Model.objects.get(id=int(id))
  except Model.DoesNotExist:
    pass
  else:
    # Do stuff here
```

Comment: hi @Vail, where does one get the `uuid.uuid4()` value?

Answer (score 2):

**This is not solution for this Question,

but mark for issue in use celery4.0.2**

output like:

```
[2017-02-09 17:45:12,136: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: [[], {}, {u'errbacks': None, u'callbacks': None, u'chord': None, u'chain': None}] (77b)
{content_type:'application/json' content_encoding:'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'redelivered': False, 'routing_key': 'test2', 'delivery_tag': 1L, 'exchange': ''} headers={'\xe5\xca.\xdb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': None, 'P&5\x07\x00': None, 'T\nKB\x00\x00\x00': '3f6295b3-c85c-4188-b424-d186da7e2edb', 'N\xfd\x17=\x00\x00': 'gen23043@hy-ts-bf-01', '\xcfb\xddR': 'py', '9*\xa8': None, '\xb7/b\x84\x00\x00\x00': 0, '\xe0\x0b\xfa\x89\x00\x00\x00': None, '\xdfR\xc4x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': [None, None], 'T3\x1d ': 'celeryserver.tasks.test', '\xae\xbf': '3f6295b3-c85c-4188-b424-d186da7e2edb', '\x11s\x1f\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x00': '()', 'UL\xa1\xfc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00': '{}'}}
```

solution:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3675

```
# call this command many times, until it says it's not installed
pip uninstall librabbitmq
```

Thanks for https://github.com/ask

Comment: If it is not solution, why did you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently librabbitmq issue is related to new default protocol in celery 4.x. You can switch to previous protocol version by either putting `CELERY_TASK_PROTOCOL = 1` in your settings if you're using Django or settings `app.conf.task_protocol = 1` in `celeryconf.py`

Then you'll be able to queue task from with another task.

Answer (score 0):

*my: [celery 3.1.25; django=1.11]*

```
ADD celery exchange in settings.py

CELERY_QUEUES = {
   "celery":       {"exchange": "celery",
                    "routing_key": "celery"}
}
```

**OR** use by this

```
# I declare queue 
ch = settings.CELERY_APP.connection().channel()
ex = Exchange("implicit", channel=ch)
q = Queue(name="implicit", routing_key="implicit", channel=ch, exchange=ex)
q.declare()   # <-- here
producer = ch.Producer(routing_key=q.routing_key, exchange=q.exchange)
# publish
producer.publish("text")
```

or U can use the second version
from kombu docs

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
task_queue = Queue('tasks', Exchange('tasks'), routing_key='tasks')

producer.publish(
    {'hello': 'world'},
    retry=True,
    exchange=task_queue.exchange,
    routing_key=task_queue.routing_key,
    declare=[task_queue], # <-- declares exchange, queue and binds.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For future comers,

In the task body, you must assign "task" and "id" values. Since the source code of consumers is written like this:

http://www.pythondoc.com/celery-3.1.11/_modules/celery/worker/consumer.html

```
   def on_task_received(body, message):
        try:
            name = body['task']
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            return on_unknown_message(body, message)

        try:
            strategies[name](message, body,
                             message.ack_log_error,
                             message.reject_log_error,
                             callbacks)
        except KeyError as exc:
            on_unknown_task(body, message, exc)
        except InvalidTaskError as exc:
            on_invalid_task(body, message, exc)
```