# RabbitMQ with Django Project and Scrapy to Push and Comume Message's

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I've Django application that is working with Celery and using RabbitMQ as message broker. I've separate project for scrapy from where I scraped data and want to push this scrapped data into rabbitMQ then django will consume this RabbitMQ message's through celery.
I need help to consume the message that pushed in rabbitMQ from scrapy project.

code snippet.

## scrapy

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    publish_message(item)    
    return item

def publish_message(data):
    import pika
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=5672))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='topic', routing_key='scrapy', body='Hello From 
     scrapy!')
    connection.close()
```

## In django app, consumers.py

```
import pika


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', heartbeat=600,
                                                               blocked_connection_timeout=300))
channel = connection.channel()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" data =============== ", data)
    # I will call celery task here once code print the data to make sure its running. unfortunately its not running. :( 
    return 


channel.basic_consume(queue='scrapy', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
print("Started Consuming...")
channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```

## celery.py

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings.development')

celery_app = Celery('my_project', broker='amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672', backend='rpc://0.0.0.0:5672')
celery_app.config_from_object(f'django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()

celery_app.conf.update(
    worker_max_tasks_per_child=1,
    broker_pool_limit=None
)

default_exchange = Exchange('default', type='topic')
scrapy_exchange = Exchange('scrapy', type='topic')

celery_app.conf.task_queues = (
Queue('scrapy', scrapy_exchange, routing_key='scrapy.#'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare a queue when consuming.
try this:

**Publisher**

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
publish_message(item)    
return item

def publish_message(data):
    import pika
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost', port=5672))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic')
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='topic', routing_key='scrapy', body='Hello From 
     scrapy!')
    connection.close()
```

**Consumer**

```
import pika


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', heartbeat=600,
                                                               blocked_connection_timeout=300))
channel = connection.channel()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" data =============== ", body)
    # I will call celery task here once code print the data to make sure its running. unfortunately its not running. :( 
    return 
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic')
channel.queue_declare(queue='scrapy')
channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic', queue='scrapy', routing_key='scrapy')
channel.basic_consume(queue='scrapy', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
print("Started Consuming...")
channel.start_consuming()
connection.close()
```

Comment: your solution worked but I'm getting this error after publishing message.
Django / Celery / Kombu worker error: Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?

Comment: This probably means Celery doesn't understand the message. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885396/django-celery-kombu-worker-error-received-and-deleted-unknown-message-wron

Comment: Ahmad I'm not using librabbitmq as you can see in my code above.
Celery , RabbitMQ, Kombu